# How do I add a user to a share in powershell without removing who is already there?

Tags: powershell

I use PDQ Deploy for deployments and part of an install requires a share and permissions to be set for the engineering team.  I made a script successfully however it overwrites what is currently there.  I like to the the group.  I can't seem to find any real way of doing this.

```
$acl = get-acl "c:\program files (x86)\Test\"
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("manftest", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.setaccessrule($ar)
set-acl "c:\program files (x86)\Test\" $acl
New-SmbShare -Name "Test" -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Test" -FullAccess "DOMAIN\manftest"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `AddAccessRule` instead of `SetAccessRule` ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemsecurity.addaccessrule?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking for add-acl to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

if I was you I will try to use icalc.exe

```
icacls.exe $path /grant "<domain\account>:(OI)(CI)(M)"
```

I have had a lot of challenges with PowerShell and setting access control lists in the past, and so I resort to using icacls in my PowerShell scripts.

Comment: I should be able to use regular commands in PDQ Deploy.  This will grant permission to folder but what about the file share?